# python Runtimeerror doesn't reappear after rerunning a cell

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I've been trying to program my own linear regression with gradient descents. While testing different learning rates I encounter with a behavior I consider a bit strange. When I am running a following cell for the first time I get an Runtimewarningss but after rerunning this single cell warnings stop popping up. I don't change any variables. Can someone explain what is going on?

The passage that cause warnings:

```
descents = dict()
for d in [GradientDescent, StochasticDescent, MomentumDescent, Adagrad]:
    best_mse_valid = np.inf
    best_lambda = np.inf
    mse_train = np.inf
    mse_test = np.inf
    loss_history = []
    print(d.__name__)
    for l in lambdas:
        model = LinearRegression(descent = d(w0, l))
        model.fit(X_train, y_train)
        est = model.calc_loss(X_valid, y_valid)
        if est < best_mse_valid:
            best_lambda = l
            mse_train = model.calc_loss(X_train, y_train)
            mse_test = model.calc_loss(X_test, y_test)
            loss_history = model.loss_history
    descents[d.__name__] = Descent(best_lambda, mse_train, mse_test, loss_history)
```

The warnings

> utils.py:363: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in scalar add return sum((self.predict(X) - y)**2)/y.shape[0]
> utils.py:363: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square return sum((self.predict(X) - y)**2)/y.shape[0]
> utils.py:343: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in matmul norm = abs(weight_difference @ weight_difference)
> utils.py:93: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in matmul return np.array([errors @ X[:,j] for j in range(X.shape[1])]) #(1d array)
> utils.py:355: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in matmul return X @ self.descent.w
> utils.py:92: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in matmul errors = X @ self.w - y #(1d array)
> utils.py:93: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in matmul return np.array([errors @ X[:,j] for j in range(X.shape[1])]) #(1d array)
> utils.py:355: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in matmul return X @ self.descent.w
> utils.py:92: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in matmul errors = X @ self.w - y #(1d array)
> utils.py:81: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply self.w -= self.eta(iteration) * gradient
> utils.py:82: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply return - self.eta(iteration) * gradient

Descent and LinearRegression classes:

```
class LinearRegression:
    """
    Linear regression class
    """

    def __init__(self, descent, tolerance: float = tolerance_default, max_iter: int = max_iter_default):
        """
        :param descent: Descent class
        :param tolerance: float stopping criterion for square of euclidean norm of weight difference
        :param max_iter: int stopping criterion for iterations
        """
        self.descent = descent
        self.tolerance = tolerance
        self.max_iter = max_iter
        self.loss_history = []

    def fit(self, X: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray) -> LinearRegression:
        """
        Getting objects, fitting descent weights
        :param X: objects' features
        :param y: objects' target
        :return: self
        """
        iteration = 1
        self.loss_history.append(self.calc_loss(X, y))
        while True:
            iteration += 1
            weight_difference = self.descent.step(X, y, iteration)
            self.loss_history.append(self.calc_loss(X, y))
            norm = abs(weight_difference @ weight_difference)
            if iteration>=self.max_iter or norm<self.tolerance:
                break
        return self
            

    def predict(self, X: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        """
        Getting objects, predicting targets
        :param X: objects' features
        :return: predicted targets
        """
        return X @ self.descent.w

    def calc_loss(self, X: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray) -> None:
        """
        Getting objects, calculating loss
        :param X: objects' features
        :param y: objects' target
        """
        return sum((self.predict(X) - y)**2)/y.shape[0]
```

```
class BaseDescent:
    """
    A base class and examples for all functions
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.w = None

    def step(self, X: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray, iteration: int) -> np.ndarray:
        """
        Descent step
        :param iteration: iteration number
        :param X: objects' features
        :param y: objects' targets
        :return: difference between weights
        """
        
        return self.update_weights(self.calc_gradient(X, y), iteration)

    def update_weights(self, gradient: np.ndarray, iteration: int) -> np.ndarray:
        """
        Example for update_weights function
        :param iteration: iteration number
        :param gradient: gradient
        :return: weight difference: np.ndarray
        """
        pass

    def calc_gradient(self, X: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        """
        Example for calc_gradient function
        :param X: objects' features
        :param y: objects' targets
        :return: gradient: np.ndarray
        """
        pass


class GradientDescent(BaseDescent):
    """
    Full gradient descent class
    """

    def __init__(self, w0: np.ndarray, lambda_: float, s0: float = s0_default, p: float = p_default):
        """
        :param w0: weight initialization
        :param lambda_: learning rate parameter (float)
        :param s0: learning rate parameter (float)
        :param p: learning rate parameter (float)
        """
        super().__init__()
        self.eta = lambda k: lambda_ * (s0 / (s0 + k)) ** p
        self.w = np.copy(w0)

    def update_weights(self, gradient: np.ndarray, iteration: int) -> np.ndarray:
        """
        Changing weights with respect to gradient
        :param iteration: iteration number
        :param gradient: gradient
        :return: weight difference: np.ndarray
        """
        self.w -= self.eta(iteration) * gradient ##????
        return - self.eta(iteration) * gradient
        

    def calc_gradient(self, X: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        """
        Getting objects, calculating gradient at point w
        :param X: objects' features
        :param y: objects' targets
        :return: gradient: np.ndarray
        """
        errors = X @ self.w - y      #(1d array)
        return np.array([errors @ X[:,j] for j in range(X.shape[1])])  #(1d array)
```

How come that after rerunning a single cell with a loop over lambdas all warnings are gone?
P.S. With other descents a situation is completely the same